# Github pull request of a branch

Tags: github

I have forked a master from upstream. I have created a branch, made some commits, and now want to issue a pull request. I want to know when my branch is merged by the user, will it get merged to the upstream master, or the user will have an option to create a new branch and merge my branch with it?  Btw, I don't have push permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the Pull Request merges depends on how you create it, when you pick four things:

- The base fork: Which fork of the repository the PR will be merged into
- The base branch: Which branch in that repository the PR will be merged into
- The compare fork: The fork with thew new code
- The compare branch: The branch containing the new code

So if you configure the base to be `upstream_repo:master`, yes, when the PR is accepted, it will be merged to `master`.

For more, see GitHub's help on [Using Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/).